# Make DynamoDB tables from multi region to one single Global table

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-dynamodb-streams

I know that AWS supports making a [single region dynamo DB to the global table](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-convert-your-single-region-amazon-dynamodb-tables-to-global-tables/) and making it available in multiple regions (as configured) using replicas.

The gist of my use case, I have got many existing dynamo DB tables provisioned in multiple regions and got data in them. I want to merge all and make them a single global table. Can you shed some light on if it's feasible or if we need to import data into one region from all others and make it global?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There’s no way to merge data between two tables, global or otherwise. You can make a global table in multiple regions then load data into them locally and have items propagate to the other regions. If you want to detect and be smart about conflicts (same item existing already in multiple tables) you might want to load all via one region.